# Desktop selection behaving incorrectly in ubuntu 21.04

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, 21.04

When I click and drag anywhere on my main display the selection box doesn’t follow my cursor. It extends to the edge of the screen. The y axis of the box also have a weird offset. It behaves correctly on my secondary monitor even if I extend the selection box to my main monitor.

[image: image showing the problem]

My main display is 34 inches @ 3440x1440, and the secondary is a 24 inch @ 3840x2160.

Answer (score 1):

It is fixed after running apt update and upgrade